# Cordova 1.6.1 setInfo error

Tags: ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I recently upgraded to cordova 1.6.1 but i can't get it to deploy on the simulator or the device itself. The debugger shows `Error: executing module 'setInfo' are you sure you have loaded iOS version of cordova-1.6.1.js?` Though i'm sure i already did. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-499?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

It turns out if you are using requireJS together with Phonegap or Cordova it can't load properly if you wrap Cordova on a require Call. So the solution would be to add this on your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="[location of cordova.ios(for ios)]"></script>
```

Also follow the link's solution found at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the steps for the upgrade? Make sure you have the updated Cordova.plist since the plug-in names have changed.

Comment: apparently i did not. what i did is copied the www and created a new project (since i installed 1.6.1 i guess it would automatically load everything)

Answer (score 0):

Yes even I had same problem I am using cordova 1.9.0 i was simply coping www folder and didnt replace necessary (ios) version of cordova.js make sure of that u must be good then.

[Guideline](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20iOS%20using%20Xcode%204)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks. it will surely work but i'm also using requireJS to my application that's why i encountered the error. It looks like phonegap is also using requirejs.